# Push the values in to an array using AngularJS

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

my service returns data from DB, now i want to push particular values from that data in to an array using AngularJS.

```
var prodData = make a call to the service.

var versionsArray = [];
```

The data returned from the service looks similar format

```
{"prodId":"31123","prodName":"IPhone","Versions":[4,5,6]}
```

Now I want to push the values of the field **"Versions":[4,5,6]** in to an array called `versionsArray`, so that later I can bind that array to a drop-down and display the versions in the drop-down.

I wanted to something in the below way

```
 Versions.push({
 id: prodData.Versions,
 value: prodData.Versions
 });
```

How do I retrieve those values an push them in to an array ?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using in your Angular service? Like a fiddler or plunkr would be helpful.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/MEZbNfBv0iFrehNPbRVe?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, Here how you can do it,

```
angular.forEach(prodData.Versions, function(version) {
    versionsArray.push(version);
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you, but prodData.Versions is showing as undefined.. when i call the service from the browser its showing the data as showed above in my post. ?

Comment: If you can make a plunker, I will resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: I tried by best to create this plunk, https://plnkr.co/edit/MEZbNfBv0iFrehNPbRVe?p=preview hope it helps you helping me.. it looks similar to this.

Comment: There were two many issues with your plunker. Please find the working here: https://plnkr.co/edit/J652pCD7XMNDbT6qHIge?p=preview

Comment: Welcome! Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can push data into an array like you normally would in plain javascript using `array.push()` method

**View**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
    <select ng-model="yourModel" ng-options="ver as ver for ver in    
     versionArray">
      <option value="">Select a version</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
function sampleCtrl($scope) {
  var data = {
    "prodId": "31123",
    "prodName": "IPhone",
    "Versions": [4, 5, 6]
  }

  $scope.versionArray = [];
  angular.forEach(data.Versions, function(item) {
    $scope.versionArray.push(item);
  });
}
```

See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7d3kwzjr/11/)